# Passing variables through click event JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was passing a parameter from an `onclick` event this way...

```
<span id="btn1" onclick="DoIt('Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3');return false;">
  Go!
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DoIt(Var1, Var2, Var3) {
  // some code...
}
</script>
```

and evertything was  working great until I realized that the page is calling the `DoSave()` function on page load.

I realize I need to encapsulate the `DoSave()` function  like this...

```
$('#btn1').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // where DoIt() code will end up...
});
```

but I'm confused about how to pass and access the variables that were attached in the onclick event..

```
onclick="DoIt('Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3');return false;"
```

How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simple use data attributes?

```
<span id="btn1" data-var="var1" data-var2="var2" data-var3="var3">
  Go!
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function(event) {
  value1 = $(this).data('var');
  value2 = $(this).data('var2');
  value2 = $(this).data('var3');
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I try to do an alert to show what I am passing, they each return 'undefined'.

Comment: @Beengie: Please update your question with complete code